# ios: gdb p (CGFloat) [[self view] center].x

Tags: objective-c, xcode, gdb

how do you p(print) a CGFLoat in Xcode gdb:

gdb p (CGFloat) [[self view] center].x

Result:

Unable to call function "objc_msgSend" at 0x184e08c: no return type information available.
To call this function anyway, you can cast the return type explicitly (e.g. 'print (float) fabs (3.0)')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast all objective-c method calls when using GDB.

```
gdb p (CGFloat) ((CGPoint)[(UIView *)[self view] center]).x
```

Comment: Actually, if your method returns an object or `id`, it does not need the cast. So only the `CGPoint` cast is required there.